# Use axios and axios-mock-adapter

Tags: javascript, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm trying to use axios and axios-mock-adapter in one place to aggregate more mocks and then export the axios instance to use it wherever I want:

mock.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

let instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});

let mock = new MockAdapter(instance);
mock.onGet('/users').reply(200, {
    users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'John Smith' }
    ]
});

export {instance}
```

main.js

```
import instance from './mock'

instance.get('/users')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Can anyone help me? What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `export default instance` instead of `export {instance}`

Answer (score 1):

main.js

```
import {instance} from './mock'
```

**Avoid default export** - it allows the exported module to be imported with any name.

Best to use named exports (wrapped in {}) to enforce consistent naming in all imports.

Comment: Named exports can also be imported with any name.  `import { foo as bar } from 'bat'`. There is no reason to avoid the default export. It is used based on whatever makes sense for your program.